# Does a type/class need to be annotated with @Component or @Service in order to annotate it's properties with @Value

Tags: java, enums, spring-annotations

We have the following code and it works for us, and we can set the value of visible thru application.properties

```
public enum Checker {
  RED ("#FF0000"),
  YELLOW ("#FFFF00");

  private final String value;

  @Value("${visible:true}")
  private String visible;

  private Checker(final String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getValue() { 
    if (visible) {
      return value; 
    }
    else {
      return "#000000";
    }
  }
}
```

Now, to better understand it, isn't it supposed to be Bean initialized before being able to do Value injections?

Comment: How does _if (visible)_ work? Isn't that a String?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes but not exactly. The correct statement is that the class instance needs to be a spring bean in order to be `@Value` to work. Adding `@Component`, `@Service` make classes spring managed bean but there are other ways as using `@Bean`.

In general spring work by changing or adding features to your declared beans by using `processor`, same as `@Transactional`, `@Value` will only take effect if it is a bean, yes you can annotate any method in any class and code will compile but spring will simple not consider it.

From @Value [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html)

> Note that actual processing of the @Value annotation is performed by a
>   BeanPostProcessor

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to annotate a class who use @value annotation
@Value means "take value from properties file" and the true from
${visible:true} means default value if not present in properties file

For a better understanding of @component, have a look on this topic:
[What's the use of @Component in spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26229602/11873420)

For @value usage you can look at this article from Baeldung:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Baeldung website is really useful for spring boot Info !
I suggest you to bookmark it ;)

I hope I could help a little !

Comment: But this only works with spring managed beans, as mentioned by your link, right? Why is the enum a spring managed bean?

Comment: Exact, I found maybe an explanation in this article.    https://www.baeldung.com/inject-properties-value-non-spring-class